# MismatchedInputException when Parsing XML using Jackson

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jackson

Can anyone help me to find what I am doing wrong here . I have to parse the below  XML String

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Person>
   <isActive>true</isActive>
   <id>A01222262</id>
   <name>Bob</name>
   <addresses>
      <address>
         <attributeName>NEWYORK_ADDRESS</attributeName>
         <attributeValue>NY 10003</attributeValue>
      </address>
      <address>
         <attributeName>CALIFORNIA_ADDRESS</attributeName>
         <attributeValue>CA 92336</attributeValue>
      </address>
   </addresses>
</Person>
```

For that I have three bean to be mapped which are as below

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
        name = "",
        propOrder = {"isActive", "id", "name", "addresses"}
)
@XmlRootElement(
        name = "Person"
)
public class Person {
    protected boolean isActive;
    @XmlElement(
            name = "Id"
    )
    protected String id;
    protected String name;
    protected Addresses addresses;
// All Setter and Getter
}
```

Addresses class is like below

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(
            name = "Addresses",
            propOrder = {"address"}
    )
    public class Addresses {
        @XmlElement(
                required = true
        )
        protected List<Address> address;
    //All Setter Getter 
}
```

And the Address Class is like below

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(
            name = "",
            propOrder = {"attributeName", "attributeValue"}
    )
    public class Address {
        @XmlElement(
                required = true
        )
        protected String attributeName;
        @XmlElement(
                required = true
        )
        protected String attributeValue;
    //All Setter Getter 
}
```

Here is the exception I am getting while parsing it

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   construct instance of `console.interceptor.Address` (although at least
>   one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to
>   deserialize from String value ('NEWYORK_ADDRESS')  at [Source:
>   (StringReader); line: 1, column: 173] (through reference chain:
>   console.interceptor.Person["addresses"]->console.interceptor.Addresses["address"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])

I am trying to parse like below

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper=new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
Person p=xmlMapper.readValue(xmlString,Person.class);  // xmlSting
```

I am using the jackson-dataformat-xml version 2.9.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your classes and able to parse it like below.I double checked with version 2.9.8 to confirm as well. Cheers!!

```
public class StackOverFlowTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
    module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(module);
    String xmlString="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><Person><isActive>true</isActive><id>A01222262</id><name>Bob</name><addresses><address><attributeName>NEWYORK_ADDRESS</attributeName><attributeValue>NY 10003</attributeValue></address><address><attributeName>CALIFORNIA_ADDRESS</attributeName><attributeValue>CA 92336</attributeValue></address></addresses></Person>";
        try {
        Person p=xmlMapper.readValue(xmlString,Person.class);
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```